# My sql syntax not working in comparing local vairaiable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_master_profile_data_temp`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `add_master_profile_data_temp`(
  IN _msisdn VARCHAR (50),  
  IN _device_identifier TEXT  
)
BEGIN
DECLARE lv_IDMsisdn BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE lv_IDDevice BIGINT  DEFAULT NULL ;
  SET     @lv_IDMsisdn := (SELECT id     FROM    `master_profile`    WHERE `msisdn` = _msisdn) ;

  SET     @lv_IDDevice := (SELECT id   FROM    `master_profile`     WHERE device_identifier =_device_identifier   AND `msisdn` <> _msisdn   AND `master_profile_status` = 1) ;  

  IF (@lv_IDDevice <> @lv_IDMsisdn)  THEN    

         SELECT  @lv_IDDevice ,@lv_IDMsisdn ,2 ;
  ELSE

         SELECT  @lv_IDDevice ,@lv_IDMsisdn ,1;
   END IF;





END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Problem is in syntax @lv_IDDevice <> @lv_IDMsisdn which is always coming as false
while on result i am getting

@lv_IDDevice    @lv_IDMsisdn    1

62  (NULL)  1

EDIT

I have even tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_master_profile_data_temp`(
  IN _msisdn VARCHAR (50),  
  IN _device_identifier TEXT  
)
BEGIN
DECLARE lv_IDMsisdn BIGINT;
DECLARE lv_IDDevice BIGINT  ;
  #SET     @lv_IDMsisdn := (SELECT id     FROM    `master_profile`    WHERE `msisdn` = _msisdn) ;

  #SET     @lv_IDDevice := (SELECT id   FROM    `master_profile`     WHERE device_identifier =_device_identifier   AND `msisdn` <> _msisdn   AND `master_profile_status` = 1) ;  


  SELECT id  INTO lv_IDMsisdn   FROM    `master_profile`    WHERE `msisdn` = _msisdn ;

  SELECT id INTO lv_IDDevice  FROM    `master_profile`     WHERE device_identifier =_device_identifier   AND `msisdn` <> _msisdn   AND `master_profile_status` = 1 ;  

  IF (lv_IDDevice IS NOT NULL AND  lv_IDDevice <> lv_IDMsisdn)  THEN     

         SELECT  lv_IDDevice ,lv_IDMsisdn ,2 ;
  ELSE

         SELECT  lv_IDDevice ,lv_IDMsisdn ,1;
  END IF;





END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `@lv_IDDevice` and `@lv_IDMsisdn` are [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). `lv_IDDevice` and `lv_IDMsisdn` are [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html), are different variables.

Comment: I needed a local variable. what correction i required in the synstax

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHgvtrxVqsTgmy6oWCGb1k/0).

Comment: See [12.3.2 Comparison Functions and Operators::<=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: wchiquito set one variable to null then check it. I am using mysql 5.6. Should i use <=> ?

Comment: If you should or should't use [12.3.2 Comparison Functions and Operators::<=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) depends what you really need. It would be possible to use it in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: I am mostly a sql server guy working in mysql from couple of years. I will try the syntax IF (`lv_IDDevice` IS NOT NULL AND  Not (`lv_IDDevice`  <=> `lv_IDMsisdn`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i end up is setting @lv_IDMsisdn to 0 incase it was null.
Like SET @lv_IDMsisdn = 0;

IT's odd why not equal not giving true result when on one side we have value while on other side we have null

Problem was the syntax

```
IF (`lv_IDDevice` IS NOT NULL AND  `lv_IDDevice`  <> `lv_IDMsisdn`)  THEN
```

One thing suggested by another user is (though i haven't tried)

```
  IF (`lv_IDDevice` IS NOT NULL AND  Not (`lv_IDDevice`  <=> `lv_IDMsisdn`))  THEN
```

Comment: could you create completely sample table, dummy data, stored procedure etc and show them up. We can help you to resolve it because now we cannot reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 things to have to consider:

**Remove 2 DECLARE statements because they are nonsense:**

```
DECLARE lv_IDMsisdn BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE lv_IDDevice BIGINT  DEFAULT NULL ;
```

**Try on below sql:**

```
SELECT @lv_IDMsisdn := id     FROM    `master_profile`    WHERE `msisdn` = _msisdn;

SELECT @lv_IDDevice :=id   FROM    `master_profile`     WHERE device_identifier =_device_identifier   AND `msisdn` <> _msisdn   AND `master_profile_status` = 1;
```

**Then, create a debug table. And see what real value from @lv_IDMsisdn and @lv_IDDevice**

```
CREATE TABLE `debug_table`( `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `DecimalValue` DECIMAL(10,6), PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );
```

-- Add 2 statements after they are set values

```
INSERT INTO `debug_table`(@lv_IDMsisdn);
INSERT INTO `debug_table`(@lv_IDDevice);
```

Comment: Not worked. Removed the declare have no effect. Problem only seems in not equal sysntax which is not working here

Comment: @KamranShahid, I updated my answer. Let's try to debug the real values. I think you didn't get the right values to compare them.